# WP7: Windows Phone 7: Is there a resource of the color/brush of the keys of the SIP?

Tags: windows-phone-7, resourcedictionary, systemcolors

I need to create my own Soft Input Panel as none of the input scopes meet my requirements. I can use `PhoneChromeBrush` as a resource for the background of the panel, but I am not able to find any resource for the color of the keys. I am talking of the keys of either the soft keyboard, soft dial pad etc. In the light theme they are plain white, but in the dark theme not.

Is there a resource I can use? Or is it just a semitransparent white overlaying? What would be the percentage of the transparency? And would it be overlaying `PhoneBackgroundBrush` or `PhoneChromeBrush`? Or does anyone know the HEX code of that color? `#3A3A3A` seems quite close, but still wrong.

Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: "Or does anyone know the HEX code of that color?" => If you want the hex color code of the keyboard, you can take a screenshot from the emulator, then get the color from a photo editing software.

Comment: Thanks KooKiz, that did the trick. Well, not quite for the resource, but for the HEX code. I did search the inet for screenshots and got their colors from paint, but never made my own screenshots. I am not sure, why these where off a bit. As I find my question answered, I did add an answer as well. But thanks for getting me on the right track.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, thanks to KooKiz, who got me on the right track, I would like to answer my own question.

This might be considered a work-a-round, but it satisfied me.

1. It seems there is no resource for this color.
2. Even the colors of the keys seem to have the same color in different
   SIPs, they are actually not. Keyboard, dial pad and even
   date-/timepicker use different colors.
3. As my soft input panel should match with the dial pad the HEX code
   of the color would be `#FF383838` in *dark theme* and `#FFFFFFFF` in *light
   theme*.
4. I am using `PhoneBackgroundBrush` covered by a semitransparent white
   (`#38FFFFFF`) to get my color. In this way in *dark theme* I will cover `#FF000000` with `#38FFFFFF` resulting in a `#FF383838`; in the *light theme* it will cover `#FFFFFFFF` with `#38FFFFFF` and the result will be `#FFFFFFFF`. So this will give me the proper color for my keys, no matter what theme the user is using.

Here an example:

```
<Grid Background="{StaticResource PhoneBackgroundBrush}" Margin="3" >
    <Grid Background="#38FFFFFF" Margin="0" >
        <TextBlock Text="1" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the "ThemeResources.xaml" file in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows Phone\v7.1\Design This will show you the HEX codes for each of the default brushes.

Be sure to check out the versions in eahc of the subfolders too so you can see the difference between the light and dark themes.

For reference, the `PhoneChromeBrush` in the dark theme is `#FF1F1F1F`

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply. I did study these ThemeResources files before. I could not find my answer in there. But this also strengthens my believe, that there is not such a resource. I did find a work-a-round suitable for my needs. I will add my answer as soon as I am allowed to do so as newbie.

Comment: Yeah, the keyboard isn't there explicitly as you can't change it and it's not a Silverlight control but you can use the equivalent/comparable values which are in the files.